# Delegate and controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the difference between the Delegate.h and Delegate.m, and ViewController.h and ViewController.m files and their usage

Answer (score 5):

A delegate is incidental to the operation of the object, whereas a controller is required. They are also on different "sides" of the object; the controller *controls* the view in question; and the object delegates functionality to its delegate, if present, putting the controller above the object and the delegate beside it.

Also, `.h` files contain declarations; `.m` files contain code, if that was what you were asking.