# Can't connect IBOutlet to header file

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsview

I have started an Objective-C application, I created a custom NSView class and assigned it to the NSTableView's view.

But now I can't connect any IBOutlet to the header file of this class, how can I resolve that?

Thanks a lot for any help possible.

EDIT: Added screenshot of re-connection with pre-entered IBOutlet:

[image: IBOutlets not connecting]

Comment: How do you mean you can't connect?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @John Woods I mean I cannot right-click and drag to header file to create a new outlet. It semi-works when using pre-entered outlets and connecting on top of them, but I get error symbols next the key paths, and don't know how to work around it.

Comment: Thanks. And what precisely do you mean by "created a custom NSView class and assigned it to the NSTableView's view"?

Comment: Really just what it says, created a new class based on NSView and then went over to interface builder, and assigned the view of the specific NSTableView to it in the inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using AppDelegate class itself, as described in [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012262-TP40012101-CH1-SW1).

For custom views I think its best to use a separate controller, as described by [juliuspaintings](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/018-NSButton-NSView.pl).

To instantiate a class in interface builder, simply follow these steps from [dbachrach](http://dbachrach.com/blog/2008/01/instantiating-an-object-in-interface-builder-on-leopard/).

For the difference between controller and delegate I would recommend this answer: [Delegate and controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700053/delegate-and-controller)